# args[] in Main for F#

Tags: f#

Here is some code In F# that I tried following the book Programming F# byChris Smith:

```
(*
Mega Hello World:
Take two command line parameters and then print
them along with the current time to the console.
*)
open System
[<EntryPoint>]
let main (args : string[]) =
    if args.Length <> 2 then
        failwith "Error: Expected arguments <greeting> and <thing>"
    let greeting, thing = args.[0], args.[1]
    let timeOfDay = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt")
    printfn "%s, %s at %s" greeting thing timeOfDay
    // Program exit code
    0
main(["asd","fgf"]) |> ignore
```

There is an error in main that says: This expression was expected to have type 'String[]' but here ahs type "a list'. But string[] is an array of string. SO I don't understand my error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`string[]` is indeed an array of strings, but `["asd", "fgf"]` is not - it's a list, which is why you get that error.

To create an array instead, use `[|"asd"; "fgf"|]` (note that, both in lists and arrays, `;` is used as a separator - `,` creates tuples).

In addition, you can't have code after a function marked as `EntryPoint`. And even if you could, calling that function makes no sense as it will already be called automatically with the command line arguments - that's the point of the `EntryPoint` attribute.

Comment: [List syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/lists) vs [Array syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/arrays)